# Existence of a nonlinear PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have a question concerning solving PDE in my research. Supposing there is a Langevin Equation.
$$ dX/dt = F(X)$$
I want to decompose it into two components which are orthogonal to each other.
$$dX/dt = F(X) = -grad(U) + Fr$$
with $(grad(U), Fr) = 0$.

However, I know that this nonlinear PDE does not always admit a solution.
$$(grad(U), F + grad(U))=0$$

For example,
$dx/dt = xy$, $dy/dy = 0$

Or
$dx/dt = -x + xy$, $dy/dt = -y$

But how to rigorously prove that it does not have solutions for some cases?

Many thanks,

Joseph Zhou